# Control not hitting SendAsync function of Custom EmailService : MVC Email confirmation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, identity

I have created a new MVC Project in Visual Studio 2013. I noticed that the `IdentityConfig.cs` file was missing. I have heard that Microsoft removed it from newer versions of ASP.NET Identity. This file, when present, used to define the `EmailService` class.

So I implement my own `EmailService` class. The code looks like this

```
//EmailService.cs
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configGMailAsync(message);
    }
    private static async Task configGMailAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
       //mailing code
    }
}
```

In my `AccountController`, I have the following `Register` method, which makes a call to `UserManager.SendEmailAsync()` method.

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("myAppName");
                UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                    new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);


                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id,
                    "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\""
                    + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

However, after the call to `UserManager.SendEmailAsync()`, the control (debugger) never hits the `SendAsync()` function of `EmailService` class.

I have another project where the `IdentityConfig.cs` was automatically added on project creation. There, after the call to `UserManager.SendEmailAsync()`, the control hits the `SendAsync()` function.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you have to register your Service with the `UserManager` class before you send the mail. Upon adding the following line just above `UserManager.SendEmailAsync()`, the `SendAsync()` function is picked up successfully:

```
UserManager.EmailService = new EmailService();
```

Here is the full function including the newly added line

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

            var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("myAppName");
            UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            UserManager.EmailService = new EmailService();

            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id,
                "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\""
                + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Web API 2 project with individual user accounts in VS 2017. There `IdentityConfig.cs` was present but it did not have an `EmailService` class. If this is the case and you do not wan't to write `UserManager.EmailService = new EmailService();` every time you wan't to use this feature you can add it here instead.

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
```